# Create a mesh from gameobjects UNITY C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have many gameobjects spawned in my scene. Is there a way to create a mesh to connect all the dots to make a solid mesh? I have researched skinned meshed but i am not sure how to use it for this purpose.

Thank you.

[image: Gameobjects I want to connect together with mesh]

Comment: I have no experience in meshes with Unity, but have you checked this? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html I think it could be a good starting point if you populate the vertices array with the center points of your objects.

Comment: You need to map the spawned units and their position (Vector3) and define which vectors represent a face in order to create the "outline" you need, then you can pass these parameters in the Mesh to create the dynamic mesh like the link describes that Andrea posted.

Answer (score 3):

You can create one mesh from multiple meshes or GameObjects with the [`Mesh.CombineMeshes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.CombineMeshes.html) function. First, create a tag named *"dots"* and make sure those objects have this tag to make them easier to find. Find all the dot GameObjects by tag with `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag`. Create array of [`CombineInstance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CombineInstance-mesh.html) and initialize each `CombineInstance` with the `mesh` and `transform` information of `MeshFilter` from each dot.

Create new GameObject to hold the new combined Objects then attach `MeshFilter` and `MeshRenderer` to it. Apply a material to it. Finally, use `MeshFilter.CombineMeshes` to combine all those meshes stored in `CombineInstance`.

```
void CombineDotMeshes(Material mat)
{
    //Find all the dots GameObjects
    GameObject[] allDots = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("dots");

    //Create CombineInstance from the amount of dots
    CombineInstance[] cInstance = new CombineInstance[allDots.Length];

    //Initialize CombineInstance from MeshFilter of each dot
    for (int i = 0; i < allDots.Length; i++)
    {
        //Get current Mesh Filter and initialize each CombineInstance 
        MeshFilter cFilter = allDots[i].GetComponent<MeshFilter>();

        //Get each Mesh and position
        cInstance[i].mesh = cFilter.sharedMesh;
        cInstance[i].transform = cFilter.transform.localToWorldMatrix;
        //Hide each MeshFilter or Destroy the GameObject 
        cFilter.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    //Create new GameObject that will contain the new combined Mesh
    GameObject combinedMesh = new GameObject("CombinedDots");
    MeshRenderer mr = combinedMesh.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    mr.material = mat;
    MeshFilter mf = combinedMesh.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();

    //Create new Mesh then combine it
    mf.mesh = new Mesh();
    mf.mesh.CombineMeshes(cInstance);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
public Material mat;

void Start()
{
    CombineDotMeshes(mat);
}
```